# Separating building and testing jobs in Jenkins

Tags: testing, jenkins, continuous-integration

I have a build job which takes a parameter (say which branch to build) that, when it completes triggers a testing job (actually several jobs) which does some stuff like download a bunch of test data and checks that the new version is works with the test data.

My problem is that I can't seem to figure out a way to show the test results in a sensible way. If I just use one testing job then the test results for "stable" and "dodgy-future-branch" get mixed up which isn't what I want and if I create a separate testing job for each branch that the build job understands it quickly becomes unmanageable because of combinatorial explosion (say 6 branches and 6 different types of testing mean I need 36 testing jobs and then when I want to make a change, say to save more builds, then I need to update all 36 by hand)

I've been looking at Job Generator Plugin and ez-templates in the hope that I might be able to create and manage just the templates for the testing jobs and have the actual jobs be created / updated on the fly. I can't shake the feeling that this is so hard because my basic model is wrong. Is it just that the separation of the building and testing jobs like this is not recommended or is there some other method to allow the filtering of test results for a job based on build parameters that I haven't found yet?

Answer (score 1):

I would define a set of simple use cases:

- Check in on development branch triggers build
- Successful build triggers UpdateBuildPage
- Successful build of development triggers IntegrationTest
- Successful IntegrationTest triggers LoadTest
- Successful IntegrationTest triggers UpdateTestPage
- Successful LoadTest triggers UpdateTestPage

etc.

So especially I wouldn't look into all jenkins job results for overviews, but create a web page or something like that.

I wouldn't expect the full matrix of build/tests, and the combinations that are used will become clear from the use cases.